# How to produce multiple horizontal error bars as shown in the link

Tags: r, graphics, plot

I am interested to produce a plot similar to figure two published in JAMA article found [here](http://jama.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=1157490&resultClick=3). I would appreciate any suggestion on how to produce similar figure in R. Sample data is found on this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_4NdfcEvU7LUXB4TW9jWWZPODA/edit?usp=sharing.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry about that. I was looking for a direction as I was not sure that the figure was made in R. Now I have added sample data and I can use ggplot2.

Comment: I have reworded the question and now the request is quite specific , thus I believe it should not be closed. For my own case the answer by MrFlick is helpful, but  the question and responses would certainly help others in future who encounter similar problem.

Comment: I think the closure of this question is unjustified. In its present form it is not broad and deserves to be reopened as it is may be useful for other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample data is extremely helpful. Thank you.

The simplest `ggplot` code would probably be

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=est, y=interaction(pollut, lag, lex.order=TRUE))) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=lcl, xmax=ucl)) + geom_vline(x=0)
```

which gives

[image]

You could start customizing with

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=est, y=lag)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=lcl, xmax=ucl)) + geom_vline(x=0) + 
    facet_grid(pollut~.) + 
    theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that the type of figure I was thinking about.